# Which of these ingredients are the acid component of a marinade?

Tags: marinade, kebab, acid

Here are some ingredients for a a sheek kebab recipe.  Which of these acts as the acid component of the marinade?

onion, lentil flour, green chilli, salt, garlic, ginger, herbs: fenugreek, fresh coriander, spices: cumin seed,coriander podwer, crushed chilli, chilli powder, garam masala(cinnamom, cloves, ginger, star anise, cumin, chilli, fennel, black pepper, bay leaves, sun. oil, nutmeg, cardamom).

Comment: This reads like a culinary school homework question.

Comment: The chiles will have a little, but nothing there is a strong acid like lemon or vinegar.

Comment: This appears to be a rub, not a marinade as there is no liquid listed.

Comment: @DebbieM i thought this was considered a marinade but seems it is not, is there a culinary term for rub method id like to research it?

Comment: @DebbieM. also please try to answer this question: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/91472/how-to-infuse-oil-to-get-same-results-as-store-bought-sheek-kebab it is related.  It's basically asking if you can rub an oil. thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about the science of rubs. I do know they are used to impart flavor, often on meat that is to be smoked or grilled.

Comment: @JamesWilson It's seekh, not sheek. Just saying.......

Comment: @dbmag9 not when taken in context of the OPs other sheek kebab perfection quest posts...

Comment: @Cindy In the UK it can be Shish, Sheesh, Sheek, Shik.... possibly depending which language it reached us via. TBH, I've never seen 'Seekh' before.

Answer (score 2):

I see no acidic elements to your "marinade."  Chili pepper (mentioned in the comments) is probably basic, rather than acidic.  As written (and as commented on) it sounds more like a rub than a marinade.  Both rubs and marinades impart flavor to the surface of proteins. Being acidic is not a requirement of a marinade.

Comment: Excellent point about the term marinade. The entymology of the word is from "sea". They were originally flavored brines.